# flask nested post data

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build in a way to handle a large number of posted options, e.g.

```
my_posted_data = {"item": "value", "item_options":{"a":2, "b":2} }
```

This would be coming from somewhere else in an api situation where I'm not in control of the environment and it is simulated for now. I'll post that through the requests library; and moving server-side, I try to get this from the route/view in my application. request.form gets read into a variable(form) which is passed to a `task_manager` queue. In the task I'll try to do:

```
options = form.get("item_options", None)
```

`options` always ends up as `NoneType`. Why is this not selecting the dict(like) value of `{"a": 2, "b": 2}`? I guess I'm doing it wrong, but what at this point I am unable to pinpoint.

Based on this scant picture I've provided, how do I post and and retrieve nested values with Flask request in the most effective way?

EDIT: I had to go a different way, using JSON data because I realized for the situation that is best, the form is more for user input from an html page, and this is something that requires a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using Flask-WTF with [Field Enclosures](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/fields.html#field-enclosures) in WTForms, you can easily handle nested post data.

Comment: I should have been more clear I know, but the data incoming is from anywhere -- its an api situation but yeah I can see the value in this. I haven't used wtforms a whole lot yet but i think its clear I might need to here rather than invest time to build my own solution. A classic case of having the basics, and then not understanding some of the finer points of making other parts more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ListField(Field):
def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
    self.data = valuelist

class ItemsForm(Form):
    a = StringField()
    b = StringField()


class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    item = StringField()
    product = ListField(FormField(ItemsForm))
```

Since FormField add default prefix, the JSON will looks like

```
{
    "item": "value",
    "product": {
        "product-a": "string",
        "product-b": "string",
    }
}
```